# Does the definition of stable system contradict itself?

Tags: linear-systems, transfer-function, laplace-transform

A system is said to be stable when any of its poles are <0.

However I don't get why that is the case. Negative poles mean negative angular frequency, and negative angular frequency is equal to positive angular frequency, so the definition contradicts itself. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A system is said to be stable when any of its poles are <0.

I'm not sure who said that, but they're wrong or they've been misquoted.

A *Linear Time Invariant* system that can be described by *ordinary differential equations* is stable if the *real part* of *every blessed one* of its poles is less than zero.

This is because for any pole $a$ in a system transfer function, nearly any response of the system to an input will have an element of the response that is proportional to $e^{a t}$.  For any $a$ such that $\mathcal R (a) < 0$, $\lim_{t \to \infty} e^{a t} = 0$.  But for any $a$ such that $\mathcal R (a) > 0$, $\lim_{t \to \infty} \left | e^{a t} \right | = \infty$.

So *even one* pole with a positive real part will cause the whole system to be unstable.

> Negative poles mean negative angular frequency

That is incorrect.  In the Laplace domain, any sinusoidal component to a signal is caused by components with $s = a + j\omega,\ \omega \ne 0$.  Your "angular frequency" is the $j\omega$ part, and it is *orthogonal* to the real number line.

> and negative angular frequency is equal to positive angular frequency

That is also incorrect.

You are probably starting with $\cos j \omega = \cos -j \omega$ and jumping to a conclusion, bolstered by the fact that in a system with all real-valued gains, the poles and zeros will all be purely real or will occur in complex-conjugate pairs.

However, while I've never seen it used in a control system, it is common in communications systems to convert a signal centered on a carrier down to baseband as an inphase/quadrature pair -- and an inphase/quadrature pair acts *just like a complex number*.

In this context (and in some hypothetical control systems context where it makes sense to have complex-valued gains), negative frequencies *do* have meaning, and a negative frequency does *not* "equal" a positive frequency -- because $e^{j\omega t} \ne e^{-j \omega t}\ \forall \ t$.